# Xcode ViewController changing issue

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having an issue when creating multiple ViewControllers in Xcode.
I want to have a few view controllers and have buttons change between them, but once I assign a button to go to the next view, the new view controller changes and I can't figure out how to fix it so that the background fits. Any solutions to this? (See pictures)

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just figured out that there was a setting called Presentation that was set to automatic, once I changed it to full screen the problem was solved.

Comment: Can you tell us where was this setting located at?